# Custom url for user profil rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to replace `my-website.com/users/41` by `my-website.com/my-profile`

This is the show view from user when i'm logged in with it. I use devise. Then i would like to do it my shopping cart.

I spent some hours to find with no result, thank you for your help.

Comment: Better to create custom route `my-profile`  and action in controller and use current_user object there.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this idea, but wondering if there is any faster way to do it.

Comment: I think that's the only fastest way. You can reuse the existing view though.

Comment: also override `after_sign_in_path_for` to point to `my-profile` page.